# Support for SHA256withECDSA signing algorithm in hashicorp vault transit sign api

Tags: hashicorp-vault, vault, transit

We have created a encryption key of type **ecdsa-p256** using /v1/transit/keys/ api and further we are signing using /v1/transit/sign/ api and trying to verify using vault it is successfully verified with valid as true but while verifying the signature using java program with SHA256withECDSA algo and public key, input and signature recieved while creation getting Exception as

**java.security.SignatureException: Invalid encoding for signature**

So is SHA256withECDSA signing algo supported for ecdsa-p256 encryption key in transit engine

here is the curl used for signing :

`curl --location 'http://localhost:8200/v1/transit/sign/test' \ --header 'X-Vault-Token: hvs.GJjDLDxW1iikrJfjK9PJgXTa' \ --header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \ --data '{ "input": "c2FtcGxlIHRleHQ=" }  '`

The result we are expecting is successfully verification of signature, public key and inputs using SHA256withECDSA signing algo if it is supported by vault .

Comment: Hi, Yash and welcome to StackOverflow! I'm pretty sure Vault adds metadata to its signature. Chances are you must parse it out before sending it to the Java API - and be careful with base64 encoding. Please help us help you and add the full text of the signature you are trying to validate.

Comment: Hi Team ,  Input sample given while signing -> dGVzdCBzdHJpbmcgc2FtcGxl  Signature received -> 
 vault:v1:MEQCICWuieeB8UhFdoP+dN59uaeiFpdkRPS3FpEN/ZotE11mAiB3MD/U39uXmKEBhJ/Vc8rZcwrDMY4EB9A4fXQ+uVXNzA== .   We are trying to verify by SHA256withECDSA algorithm using java program.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. But cryptography is all or nothing. Show us 1) the command line you used to extract the key, 2) how you load the key in your code, and 3) the actual signature verification. The code should be 10-15 lines max. If necessary, write a one-off method that reproduces the problem and paste it here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `vault:v1:` and base64 decode the rest of the signature and use these bytes in Java.

So if Vault gives you:

```
vault:v1:MEQCICWuieeB8UhFdoP+dN59uaeiFpdkRPS3FpEN/ZotE11mAiB3MD/U39uXmKEBhJ/Vc8rZcwrDMY4EB9A4fXQ+uVXNzA==
```

You will end up with these bytes (not characters, line wrapped for pretty printing):

```
3044022025ae89e781f148457683fe74de7db9a7a216976444f4b716910d
fd9a2d135d66022077303fd4dfdb9798a101849fd573cad9730ac3318e04
07d0387d743eb955cdcc
```

This `openssl` and `xxd` command will provide you with those bytes (ymmv):

```
$ openssl base64 -d -A <<< 'MEQCICWuieeB8UhFdoP+dN59uaeiFpdkRPS3FpEN/ZotE11mAiB3MD/U39uXmKEBhJ/Vc8rZcwrDMY4EB9A4fXQ+uVXNzA==' | xxd -p
```

Comment: This will get rid of the `Invalid encoding for signature` message. If you run into another error, ask a new question.

Comment: Hi, I have tried with your above solution with commands given for openssl but we are again encountering the same error when we are trying to verify by java program using sha256withECDSA algo .                                                                                              sample signature used for verifying --> 3044022025ae89e781f148457683fe74de7db9a7a216976444f4b716910d
fd9a2d135d66022077303fd4dfdb9798a101849fd573cad9730ac3318e04
07d0387d743eb955cdcc